# Can SSL_Write return with a value > 0 but less than bytes asked to write?

Tags: c, sockets, openssl, nonblocking

```
int SSL_write(SSL *ssl, const void *buf, int num);
result = SSL_write(pSsl, buf, 8);
```

If result is bigger than 0, can it be smaller than 8?
Then, what do I do?

**Note**: This is for non blocking sockets (for blocking it can defineately not happen I think).

Answer (score 4):

Openssl [SSL_write](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_write.html) docs page says,

> **SSL_write() will only return with success, when the complete contents of buf of length num has been written**. This default behaviour can be changed with the SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE option of SSL_CTX_set_mode. When this flag is set, SSL_write() will also return with success, when a partial write has been successfully completed. In this case the SSL_write() operation is considered completed. The bytes are sent and a new SSL_write() operation with a new buffer (with the already sent bytes removed) must be started. A partial write is performed with the size of a message block, which is 16kB for SSLv3/TLSv1.

Blocking or non-blocking SSL socket, if the return value of `SSL_write()` is greater than zero, unless `SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE` is set, it is expected from `openssl` library that the return value only be equal to the number of bytes requested to be sent as per their documentation.

Comment: @SoftWare: Did this answer your question ? If not, care to comment on what else you are looking for ?

Comment: [This thread from 2006](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/SSL-MODE-ACCEPT-MOVING-WRITE-BUFFER-td6421.html) ([archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20160524231151/http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/SSL-MODE-ACCEPT-MOVING-WRITE-BUFFER-td6421.html)) explains the details of why `SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE` exists and why it's needed for correctness. The farther down in that thread you go, the clearer the explanations become.